# Nexus 6 NFC & Phone Stop working on setup. Cant flash!

Tags: nexus-6

Basically when i start up the device right after a factory reset, it boots up just like it should, but it then says that Phone stopped working. Then it says the nfc process stopped working. The second you press ok, they pop up again. BUT there is a split milisecond before they pop up again. SO, for the past hour, i have been pressing the ok button twice, then dialing in one key on the keyboard before they pop up again.

However i have ran into an issue. The bottom buttons "next" dont work. I have tried many times but it seems like i cant continue :(

- The OEM is LOCKED
- Since it is reset, i cant unlock it without going into the settings

How am i supposed to get the messages away? Fix? Anything?

Comment: Seems like some parts of your ROM have gone corrupt. Have you considered reflashing your device's [factory image?](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I couldn't reflash it or do anything instead of getting a new phone I ended up spending 45 minutes clicking the OK button and using the split second time to navigate to set up then I navigated to the settings and turn on the developer options which allowed me to install the factory image. I could not flash anything because I didn't have a custom recovery boot.

apparently the 5.1 update that I installed was the OTA update but you didn't contain the entire wrong of the system. The reason the phone and NFC were not working is because Google created an update which allows the SIM cards to be in multiples so you can have multiple carriers. This change some of the code which means of 5.0. 1 in the 5.1 updates were conflicting because the 5.0.s and which caused the phone and NFC which use may have changed my currents and which caused the phone and NFC which use my networking radio failed. the OTA update I install was about 400 megabytes the actual image was about 800 so I installed be full recovery and it worked and I'm currently using the same phone to write this message.